# Making clock in javascript but Raphael not defined

Tags: raphael

I am making a clock in javascript. The code below is just the start. It should produce an orange rectangle only.

I am using the raphael library for the vector graphics.

However, when i try and view this in a web browser, in the inspect element i get a message saying that raphael is undefined.

I have stored my clock.html and clock.js file in a folder that contains only raphael-min.js

I have the html code as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="Clock.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src=“raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and the java code as follows

```
window .onload= function (){
var paper = new Raphael( 0, 0, 400, 400);
var backGround = paper.rect(0, 0, 400, 400);
backGround.attr({ fill: "orange"});
/* Comment - Add your code here*/
};`
```

If someone could please tell me what I am doing wrong, that would be fantastic. In plain english please. I started learning html and javascript last week.

Many thanks

Comment: You need to put the raphael-min.js script before your code so that Raphael is defined before it is used.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that and let you know in a sec if it works

Comment: Unfortunately it still is not working. I have changed the html code to 
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script src=“raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<html>

<head>

<script src="Clock.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>


<body>

</body>

</html>

Comment: In the [example in black on Raphael main page](http://raphaeljs.com/) they don't use `new` with `Raphael()`.  [My last Raphael-based project](https://github.com/DrPaulBrewer/meteor-satchat/blob/master/client/app.js) doesn't use `new` with `Raphael()` either.  (see function makeWorld ~ line 373).  Assuming, of course, the raphael-min script is loaded first as discussed under my deleted answer.

Comment: I didnt see you mention that under your deleted answer. Did you delete it? I have tried both with and without new! I have used matlab and SAS before so i know a bit of actual code, have tried all sorts of ways. what do you mean by the raphael script is loaded first?

Comment: I restored the deleted answered.  Try [this jsfiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/8beuvrvs/2/) it works fine here I see the orange rectangle when I click run. Jsfiddle doesn't need your html code, it includes correct script tags already.  I've tried removing `new` from the code at `= new Raphael(...)`and it works without new and it also works with new.

Comment: To answer your question about loading, when the browser requests a web page, first it asks the server for the HTML file.  Then it asks for each javascript, css, image, etc mentioned in the HTML file.  The scripts are executed in the order that they are mentioned in the HTML file.  Therefore, if the `<script src="Clock.js">` appears first, before raphael-min.js, the browser will execute Clock.js before raphael-min.js.   When the browser executes Clock.js, it will see the call to `Raphael()`, and treat it as a call to an undefined function, an error that stops execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always add the scripts your code uses before you add your code.

Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src=“raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="Clock.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In the question, Clock.js appears first.  That's probably why you are getting the Raphael undefined error.

I removed `type="text/javascript"`. You'll find that in older JS books and tutorials but it is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had actually tried that already and just tried copy and pasting to make sure it is the same and it is. I have downloaded the uncompressed version of raphael and it is named the same as in my code, raphael-min.js

Comment: It is still however not working! I have all 3 files saved in a folder on my desktop. Raphael is 298KB big. I have done something wrong with raphael and I just dont know what. My javascript file clock.js is as above still..I have also tried the online link instead but still no damn orange rectangle. thanks

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. It was actually just not working in chrome and worked in Internet explorer! Thanks very much for your well explained answers.

Comment: Many thanks. I am now trying to implement a digital clock onto my analogue clock and make some buttons which change the time. Check out my most recent question if you fancy having a look. Otherwise, thanks for your help and patience :)